# Как начать таймер с начала после нажатия кнопки?

Tags: javascript, таймер

Пытаюсь сделать возобновление таймера.

Сначала есть квадрат и таймер, по истечении таймера квадрат исчезает и появляется кнопка "Повторить". После ее нажатия таймер должен отсчитывать снова, но цифры не сменяются одна за другой, есть только начальная цифра.

При этом сам таймер работает: по истечении времени квадрат исчезает.

Как сделать так, чтобы цифры таймера после нажатия кнопки отображались?

```
const labelTimer = document.querySelector('span')
const div = document.querySelector('div')
const title = document.querySelector('h1')
const button = document.querySelector('button')

let timer

function start() {
    let time = 5;
    function tick() {

      const seconds = time % 60
      labelTimer.textContent = `${seconds}`;
     
      if (time == 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        div.style.opacity = 0
        title.textContent = 'Квадрат исчез!'
        button.style.opacity = 100
      }
      time--;
    }
    tick();
    const timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
    return timer;
  }

start()

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    title.innerHTML = `Этот квадрат исчезнет через: <span>5</span> секунд`
    div.style.opacity = 100
    button.style.opacity = 0
    timer = start();
})
```

Comment: Было бы не плохо, увидеть вашу HTML разметку, с которой вы проводите данные манипуляции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если придерживаьтся вашего кода, то достаточно перенести селекторы h1 и span внутрь фукнции и все будет работать как задумано:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div')
const button = document.querySelector('button')
let timer

function start() {
  let time = 5;
  const title = document.querySelector('h1');
  title.innerHTML = `Этот квадрат исчезнет через: <span>5</span> секунд`
  const labelTimer = document.querySelector('span');

  function tick() {

    const seconds = time % 60
    labelTimer.textContent = `${seconds}`;

    if (time === 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      div.style.opacity = 0
      title.textContent = 'Квадрат исчез!'
      button.style.opacity = 100
    }
    time--;
  }
  tick();
  const timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
  return timer;
}

start()

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  div.style.opacity = 100
  button.style.opacity = 0
  timer = start();
})
```

```html
<h1>Этот квадрат исчезнет через: <span>5</span> секунд</h1>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #20c997"></div>
<button>Начать</button>
```

Ну или можно немно оптимизировать. Запуск таймера осуществляется только по кнопке

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div')
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const title = document.querySelector('h1');
let timer;

function start() {
  let time = 5;

  function tick() {
    title.innerHTML = `Этот квадрат исчезнет через: <span>${time % 60}</span> секунд`;

    if (time-- === 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      div.style.opacity = '0';
      title.innerHTML = 'Квадрат исчез!';
      button.style.opacity = '100';
    }
  }
  tick();
  return setInterval(tick, 1000);
}

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  div.style.opacity = '100';
  button.style.opacity = '0';
  timer = start();
});
```

```html
<h1>Квадрата нет!</h1>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #20c997; opacity: 0"></div>
<button>Начать</button>
```

Comment: Все получилось! Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Bemfes Если ответ устраивает нажмите галочку "Принять ответ" слева. За хорошие ответы, можно и проголосовать

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы создаёте новый элемент, используя запись в innerHtml. Вам нужно перепределять labelTimer каждый раз после того как вы это делаете (т.к. сейчас у вас после нажатия на кнопку в переменной labelTimer содержится ссылка на дом элемент, которого уже нет в дереве, а на экране уже новый), либо менять текст другим способом, не подразумевающим создание нового span при каждом нажатии на кнопку, либо переписывать весь текст вместе с цифрой и пересозданием спана каждый тик

Comment: Да, у меня были подозрения, спасибо за ответ!